# How to retrieve an instruction's disassembly from a MachineInstr?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llc

I need to debug a `MachineFunctionPass` I'm developing. I'm targeting the `x86` architecture.

How do I retrieve the target disassembly from a `MachineInstr` instance?

### Example `MachineInstr` representation

```
dead renamable $eax = MOV32rm $ebp, 1, $noreg, 12, $noreg :: (load 4 from %fixed-stack.1)
```

### Expected disassembly (Intel syntax)

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+0x12]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In general – no, because some things are not finalized at MI level (e.g. it could contain virtual registers before RA or stack slots like in your examples before stack slot allocation), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any workaround or a different way (starting from a `MachineInstr` to achieve something similar?

Comment: I don't see what you could "workaround" here. Target assembler is available after MI => MC lowering at assembly printing stage.

Comment: I meant if there may be a way, starting from a `MachineInstr`, to print the target's disassembly. You mentioned the `MI -> MC` lowering phase, could this work out to achieve my goal? Could you point me to a significant code snippet that may help? Thanks!